# Buddy selected signal in Pidgin API

Tags: plugins, pidgin

I'm writing a plugin for Pidgin and I need to catch one special event - I need to react when you click/select a "buddy" in the "buddy list" in Pidgin.

Please, guys do you know if there is such signal (I guess this is where it should be listed, if it would exist - https://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/2.5.2/html/blist-signals.html)? If not, could you imagine some workaround?

If no other option, I'll try to modify directly Pidgin code, it's hard for me, I'm quite new to C and Pidgin project is not small, but I'm interested enough to it, so why not :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a pidgin-level signal for this. To catch this you would need to be writing a GTK+ plugin and you would need to connect to the appropriate signal on the buddy list tree view widget itself.

Comment: Hi, yes, you are true. Actually, I've made some modifications in Pidgin source codes and now there is such signal, it works. Later, I'll ask Pidgin developers, if they are interested in such thing.